# How come my canvas shadow blur is thicker for some lines but not with others?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Does anyone know why canvas shadowblur is being applied more prominently on the left side of the tree? if i remove the shadow blur, it still looks like the lines are thicker on the left side of the tree. it seems like branches on the left side are being drawn over multiple times? am i doing the recursion incorrectly or is it something else? If I make each line its own separate path by bringing the ctx.beginPath() call inside the recursive function, it fixes the problem of lines being thicker, but now the shadow blur effect does not show up. what am I doing wrong?

images:
[with blur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eHka.png)
[without blur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCyKf.png)

```
generateFractal(ctx, grammar, sentence, branchSize) {
    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height);
    ctx.shadowColor = "teal";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 14;
    const drawRecursive = (ctx, sentence, idx, branchSize) => {
      if (idx === sentence.length) return;
      if (sentence[idx] === "1" || sentence[idx] === "0") {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(0, -branchSize);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.translate(0, -branchSize);
        ctx.closePath();
      } else if (sentence[idx] === "[") {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 4);
      } else if (sentence[idx] === "]") {
        ctx.restore();
        ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 4);
      }
      drawRecursive(ctx, sentence, idx + 1, branchSize);
    };
    drawRecursive(ctx, sentence, 0, branchSize);
  }
```

Tried changing how paths were being created. that fixed the issue where lines were inconsistent thickness, but it made it so shadowblur does not work anymore. i tried setting the shadowblur settings before the recursive call, before generateFractal, as well as before and after the beginPath() call inside the recursive function.

Comment: Do the lines get thinner and thinner consistently E.g. with a more complex structure? Could you show us the sentence which produced the images you have shown? The only suspicion i have is that the rotation and restoration gradually nobble things, but I don’t see why they should unless it’s a cumulative rounding error.

Comment: Ah, just noticed that you did use a method to make the lines equal. What was it?

Comment: Certainly because your code asks to draw multiple times at the same position. A simple fix would be to not call `beginPath` in your recursive function but only at the end when all the path has been defined. A better fix would be to remove the duplicate segments. The best being doing both, because shadowing is consumptive but the complexity of the path doesn't add much to it, so better to render only once.